# Scraping soundcloud.com with rvest package in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to scrape the this [URL](https://soundcloud.com/charts/top?genre=all-music&country=CA) to get the names of the top 50 soundcloud artists in Canada.

Using SelectorGadget, I selected the artists names and it told me the path is '.sc-link-light'.

My first attempt was as follows:

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(reshape2)

soundcloud <- read_html("https://soundcloud.com/charts/top?genre=all-music&country=CA")

artist_name <- soundcloud %>% html_nodes('.sc-link-light') %>% html_text()
```

which yielded artist_name as a list of 0.

My second attempt I changed the last line to:

```
artist_name <- soundcloud %>% html_node(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", ".sc-link-light", " " ))]') %>% html_text()
```

which again yielded the same result.

What exactly am I doing wrong? I believe this should give me the artists names in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webpage you are attempting to scrape is dynamic.  As a result you will need to use a library such as RSelenium.  A sample script is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RSelenium)
library(rvest)
library(stringr)

url <- "https://soundcloud.com/charts/top?genre=all-music&country=CA"

rD <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")
remDr <- rD[["client"]]


remDr$navigate(url)
pg <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
artist_name <- pg %>% html_nodes('.sc-link-light') %>% html_text()


####clean up####
remDr$close()
rD$server$stop()
rm(rD, remDr)
gc()

system("taskkill /im java.exe /f", intern=FALSE, ignore.stdout=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you Blue050205, I am actually working on Rstudio cloud and as you can imagine, this did not work that well. However, I did some reading on RSelenium, and I am marking this as answered on the basis that I believe your solution will work. I will save this as reference for future use on web scraping projects involving dynamic web pages. Thank your for your help.